# How to enforce/ensure Java hotspot JIT compilation at a certain moment

Tags: java, performance, jvm-hotspot

The problem i'm interested in at the moment is profiling/optimizing some piece of code. General recommendation for profiling with Java is "run", "wait for some time for hotspot JIT compiler to do its job", "repeat the test" ...

So the questions are

- how long shoud I wait for hotspot to start and complete its job?
- will JIT run while CPU is rather saturated (by other threads)? - it may happen in real life that process constantly loads CPU up to 100%.
- how many executions of the same piece of code is needed to identify the "hot spots"?
- is it possible to somehow magically (probably using some proprietary API of the Oracle JVM) to trigger JIT compilation for certaing classes?

Comment: You're probably better off using a pre-built framework to deal with all of these problems, like [Caliper](https://code.google.com/p/caliper/).

Comment: try JMH(Java Microbenchmark Harness) http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-performance/jmh.html

Comment: @LouisWasserman Caliper was proven to be incompetently designed by Google. It just can't deal with OSR gracefully. JMH is the golden standard of microbenchmarking in Java.

Comment: @WojciechKudla: at the time that comment was written, JMH had not even had [an 0.1 release](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/rev/34c700cd00fe).  I agree JMH is the golden standard today.

Answer (score 0):

> how long shoud I wait for hotspot to start and complete its job?

About 10,000 calls/iterations and a few milli-seconds.

> will JIT run while CPU is rather saturated (by other threads)? - it may happen in real life that process constantly loads CPU up to 100%.

Yes, it may take longer, but performing test at 100% of CPU it's usually a good idea as the results are less likely to be representative of what you would do in production.

> how many executions of the same piece of code is needed to identify the "hot spots"?

I would wait until the code has warmed up where possible.  Realistic test data, a few seconds at high CPU utilisation and a decent profiler is usually enough.

> is it possible to somehow magically (probably using some proprietary API of the Oracle JVM) to trigger JIT compilation for certaing classes?

Other than running it enough times no.  Compiling the class too early can lead to sub-optimal code.  The code is optimised based on how it is used. JRockit (which is also owned by Oracle) has/had such a feature.